# jquery not firing code inside datatables declaration

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have the following code:

```
let checkedValues=new Array();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    table = jq('#example').DataTable( {
             "select":{
                "style": "multi"
             },
             "order":[[1,"asc"]],
             "dom": "Bfrtip",
             "bLengthChange":false,
             "ajax": '/en/users/api/get-users',
             "columnDefs": [ 
                    {
                        "orderable":false,
                        "className":"select-checkbox",
                        "targets":0,
                        "width":"5%"
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": -1,
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info smallPadding edit'>Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-success smallPadding export'>Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger smallPadding delete'>Delete</button>"
                    },
                    ],
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "text": "Get selected data",
                            "action": function () {
                                table.rows( { selected: true } ).each(function() {
                                   var row = table.row(jq(this)).data();
                                   checkedValues.push(row[1]);                                   
                                })
                                events.empty();
                                let count=1;
                                events.prepend( '<div>'+count+' row(s) selected</div>' );
                            }                            
                        }
                    ],                    
                  }); 
                  jq('#example .select-checkbox').on('click', function () {
                    alert(1);
                    var data = table.row( jq(this) ).data();
                    checkedValues.push(data[1]);             
                });                                                            
            });
```

You'll see there is code `jq('#example .select-checkbox').on('click', function () {` which doesnt seem to take effect. I know it works because i can manually put it in my console and it operates fine.

Not sure what to do at this point. I also tried taking it out of the `jq(document).ready`

UPDATE:

i was able to get it working with a timeout but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can move that code into an `initComplete()` function, so the click event will not be added until the DataTable has finished initializing:

```
"buttons": [...],
"initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
    jq('#example .select-checkbox').on('click', function () { 
        alert(1);
    });
}
```

Reference [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete).